# How can I fix Homestead Vagrant error "Configuring and enabling network interfaces... `await_response_state': Agent pid 3330 (RuntimeError)"

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox, homestead, vagrantfile

I'm using [Laravel 7.x Homestead](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/homestead#introduction). Everything had been working fine for years, maybe until around the time I upgraded from 6.x to 7.x (though I'm not sure because I don't frequently try to reload).

Now whenever I run `cd /c/code/Homestead/ && vagrant up` or `cd /c/code/Homestead/ && vagrant reload --provision` this happens:

```
==> vboxHomestead: Machine booted and ready!
==> vboxHomestead: Checking for guest additions in VM...
    vboxHomestead: The guest additions on this VM do not match the installed version of
    vboxHomestead: VirtualBox! In most cases this is fine, but in rare cases it can
    vboxHomestead: prevent things such as shared folders from working properly. If you see
    vboxHomestead: shared folder errors, please make sure the guest additions within the
    vboxHomestead: virtual machine match the version of VirtualBox you have installed on
    vboxHomestead: your host and reload your VM.
    vboxHomestead:
    vboxHomestead: Guest Additions Version: 6.0.0 r127566
    vboxHomestead: VirtualBox Version: 6.1
==> vboxHomestead: Setting hostname...
==> vboxHomestead: Configuring and enabling network interfaces...
C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.7/gems/net-scp-1.2.1/lib/net/scp.rb:398:in `await_response_state': Agent pid 3330 (RuntimeError)
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.7/gems/net-scp-1.2.1/lib/net/scp.rb:369:in `block (3 levels) in start_command'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.7/gems/net-ssh-5.1.0/lib/net/ssh/connection/channel.rb:323:in `process'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.7/gems/net-ssh-5.1.0/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:250:in `block in ev_preprocess'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.7/gems/net-ssh-5.1.0/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:540:in `each'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.7/gems/net-ssh-5.1.0/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:540:in `each_channel'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.7/gems/net-ssh-5.1.0/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:250:in `ev_preprocess'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.7/gems/net-ssh-5.1.0/lib/net/ssh/connection/event_loop.rb:101:in `each'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.7/gems/net-ssh-5.1.0/lib/net/ssh/connection/event_loop.rb:101:in `ev_preprocess'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.7/gems/net-ssh-5.1.0/lib/net/ssh/connection/event_loop.rb:29:in `process'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.7/gems/net-ssh-5.1.0/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:228:in `process'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.7/gems/net-ssh-5.1.0/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:181:in `block in loop'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.7/gems/net-ssh-5.1.0/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:181:in `loop'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.7/gems/net-ssh-5.1.0/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:181:in `loop'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.7/gems/net-ssh-5.1.0/lib/net/ssh/connection/channel.rb:272:in `wait'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.7/gems/net-scp-1.2.1/lib/net/scp.rb:284:in `upload!'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.7/gems/vagrant-2.2.7/plugins/communicators/ssh/communicator.rb:327:in `block (2 levels) in upload'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.7/gems/vagrant-2.2.7/plugins/communicators/ssh/communicator.rb:333:in `block in upload'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.7/gems/vagrant-2.2.7/plugins/communicators/ssh/communicator.rb:742:in `block in scp_connect'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.7/gems/vagrant-2.2.7/plugins/communicators/ssh/communicator.rb:382:in `connect'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.7/gems/vagrant-2.2.7/plugins/communicators/ssh/communicator.rb:740:in `scp_connect'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.7/gems/vagrant-2.2.7/plugins/communicators/ssh/communicator.rb:303:in `upload'
...
```

Additionally, trying to destroy the box causes a similar error:

```
vagrant destroy
==> vboxHomestead: Running action triggers before destroy ...
==> vboxHomestead: Running trigger...
==> vboxHomestead: Backing up mysql database homestead...
==> vboxHomestead: Trigger run failed
C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.7/gems/net-scp-1.2.1/lib/net/scp.rb:398:in `await_response_state': Agent pid 4861 (RuntimeError)
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.7/gems/net-scp-1.2.1/lib/net/scp.rb:369:in `block (3 le...
```

unless and until I comment out `backup: true` in the Homestead.yaml. Then `vagrant destroy` works, and then `vagrant up` works, and I use the machine for a while, and eventually I run into this problem all over again later.

How can I narrow down where the problem is?

I'm using Vagrant 2.2.7, VirtualBox 6.1.4, Homestead v10.5.1, which uses box 'laravel/homestead' version '9.3.0'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The maintainer of Homestead [says](https://github.com/laravel/homestead/issues/1394#issuecomment-609825858):

> We can't guarantee results of `vagrant reload --provision` and I generally advise against using it unless you're really comfortable with what Vagrant is doing and what your provisioners are doing.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and found it was caused by the login profile (/etc/profile or /etc/prfile.d/*) echoing something to the terminal. I think you will find that text "Agent pid 3330" is coming from one of the profiles when you login as root. Comment that out and the problem should go away or exclude echoing messages when logged in as root.